# Linux : receive from socket with timeout?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, graphics

I have an graphics application , where data comes from server whenever there is an update in the screen. (Incremental update). I am observing that when there is no data coming from server , after some time socket is getting closed.
is there any way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Is UDP or TCP in use?

Comment: sorry for not mentioning it , it is tcp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the "TCP keepalive" is what you need. You can get more information in this web page: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/programming.html